# Merge sort in Python - `int` object is not iterable

Tags: python, algorithm, mergesort

Here is merge sort implementation in Python. I am getting the error `int object is not iterable` when `merge_arrays()` function is called. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
arr = [1,5,4,7,6,8,3,2,9]

def merge_arrays(_arr_left, _arr_right):
    sorted_arr = []
    left, right = 0, 0

    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        if (_arr_left[left] < _arr_right[right]):
            sorted_arr.extend(_arr_left[left])
            left += 1
        else:
            print _arr_right[right], right
            sorted_arr.extend(_arr_right[right])
            right += 1

    return sorted_arr

def merge_sort(_arr):
    if (len(_arr) <= 1):
        return _arr

    _arr_left = merge_sort(_arr[:len(_arr)/2])
    _arr_right = merge_sort(_arr[(len(_arr)/2):])

    return merge_arrays(_arr_left, _arr_right)

try:
    merge = merge_sort(arr)
    print merge
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Comment: Include the full traceback. It's got important things like the line with the error. That said, it looks like you're calling `.extend()` on elements of the lists. You might want to use `.append()`.

Comment: @Cyphase `append` did work and now the error is `list index out of range`

Comment: @user4812502 you might want to consider what the length of the arrays (left, right) are as you recurse down and ask yourself what values the indexes (left, right) can take given the number of times you loop `for i ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other answers have mentioned, you need to change `extent` to `append`. However, as you said in comments, you are getting `list index out of range` error because you are iterating over the `size` of `arr` which is `9` but subarrays have much lesser length. Try changing your merging two arrays code to the following.

```
while (len(_arr_left) > left) or (len(_arr_right) > right):
        if (len(_arr_left) > left) and (len(_arr_right) > right):
            if (_arr_left[left] < _arr_right[right]):
                sorted_arr.append(_arr_left[left])
                left += 1
            else:
                sorted_arr.append(_arr_right[right])
                right += 1
        elif (len(_arr_left) > left):
            sorted_arr.append(_arr_left[left])
            left += 1
        else:
            sorted_arr.append(_arr_right[right])
            right += 1
```

As you can see in the above code, we have to test for various conditions. If both subarrays contains elements, then we compare them to each other and `append` to `sorted_arr` depending on the value evaluation. If not then we `append` values from individual `sub-arrays`. It would have been easier if instead of using `left` and `right`, you were using `pop` so you wouldn;t have to keep tracking of `left` and `right`

Finally, [here](https://ideone.com/4e1751) is the working version of your code. You also need to modify 
`return merge_sort(...)` to `sorted_arr = merge_sort(...) return sorted_arr` so it doesn't print everytime it returns `sorted_arr`

Answer (score 2):

That particular error is coming from the fact that you're saying `sorted_array.extend(_arr_left[left])`.  You're asking for `sorted_array` to have appended to it every element of the "iterable" `_arr_left[left]`.  But `_arr_left[left]` isn't really iterable, it's just whatever int is at index `left` in `_arr_left`.

If you don't `try` then `except` and print the `Exception`, you'll see a full stack trace that will tell you which line is bad.

```
  File "merge.py", line 27, in <module>
    merge = merge_sort(arr)
  File "merge.py", line 22, in merge_sort
    _arr_left = merge_sort(_arr[:len(_arr)/2])
  File "merge.py", line 22, in merge_sort
    _arr_left = merge_sort(_arr[:len(_arr)/2])
  File "merge.py", line 25, in merge_sort
    return merge_arrays(_arr_left, _arr_right)
  File "merge.py", line 9, in merge_arrays
    sorted_arr.extend(_arr_left[left])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

So you can see the problem starts at line 9.  You can also insert `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` before you think the Exception comes up to run the [python debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) and step through your program's progression to see where the Exception appears.

Comment: thanks for answering.  `append` did work and now the error is `list index out of range`

Comment: Right, that's a different question.  Replace the big `try`-`except` block
with just `merge = merge_sort(arr)` alone so you can see the whole stack trace and figure out where you're going wrong.  For interactive help with your program, you may want to [go to the python chat](https://www.python.org/community/irc/).

Comment: removing `try/except block` only displays `runtime error`. I appreciate your suggestion for chat but I think it would be better if I can try to solve it myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your line 9:

```
sorted_arr.extend(_arr_left[left])
```

- `sorted_arr` is a `list`
- `_arr_left` is a `list`
- `left` is an `int`

### So, the problem is:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a.extend(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>>
```

### Solution:

You can use [`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) instead of `extend()`.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a.append(5)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

**PS:** You might have other issues with your code.

Comment: thanks for answering.  `append` did work and now the error is `list index out of range` just like you said in **you might have ... your code**